# Database: Storing multiple Types in single table or multiple intermediate tables for Delta Tables

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, create-table, audit-trail

Using Java and Oracle.

We need to update changes in Email, UserID of employee to third party. 
Actual table is Employee and intermediate table we keep which we will use for comparison of changes before sending to third party.

Following are database designs coming in mind for intermediate table:

Only Single table:

```
EmployeeiD|Value|Type|UpdateDate
```

`Value` is userid or email, `type` will be `'email'` or `'userid'`. Update date is kept so to figure out that which of email or userid was different and update to third party.

Multiple Table:

```
 Employee_EmailID
      EmpId|EmailID|Updatedate

 Employee_UserID
      EmpId|UserID|Updatedate
```

Java flow will be:

- Pick employee from actual table.
- Pick employee from above intermediate table.
- Compare differences. Update difference to third party.
- Update above table with updated value and last update date.

Which one is consider as best way, single table approach or multiple table or is there any standard way to implement the same? There are 10,000 Employees in system.

Intermediate table is just storing Delta records i.e Records transferred to third party so that it can be compared next day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good database design has separate tables for different concepts. Using the same database column to hold different types of data will lead to code which is harder to understand, prone to data corruption and less performative.

You may think it's only two tables and a few tens of thousands of rows, so does it matter? But that is only your current requirement. What you choose now will set the template for what happens when (say) you need to add telephone numbers to the process.

---

> Now in future if we get 5 more entities to update

Do you mean "entities", like say Customers rather than Employees? Or do you really mean "attributes" as in my example of Employee Telephone Number?

Generally speaking we have a separate table for distinct entities, and all the attributes of that entity are grouped at the same cardinality. To take your example, I would expect an Employee to have one UserID and one Email Address so I would design the table like this:

```
Employee_audit
      EmpId|UserID|EmailID|Updatedate
```

That is, I have one record which stores the complete state of the Employee record at the `Updatedate`.

If we add a new entity, Customers then we have a new table. Simple. But a new attribute like Employee Phone Number offers a choice, because an employee can have more than one: work landline, mobile, fax, home, etc. So we could represent this in three ways: a child table with a type column, multiple child tables for each type, or as distinct columns on the Employee record.

For the main Employee table I would choose the separate table (or tables, depending on whether I'm shooting for 6NF). But for an audit table I would choose one record per Employee and pivot the phone numbers like this:

```
Employee_audit
      EmpId|UserID|EmailID|Landline|Mobile|Fax|Home|Updatedate
```

The one thing I would never do is have a single table with `type` and `value` columns. It seems attractive because it means we could track additional entities without any further DDL. But in fact it becomes harder to re-assemble **the complete state** of an Employee at any given time with each attribute we add. Also it means the auditing process itself is more complicated (because it needs to determine which attributes have changed and whether it needs to audit the change) and more expensive (because changing three attributes on the same record entails inserting three audit records).

Comment: Now in future if we get 5 more entities to update. Will it be good to create separate table for each and in future it would be 10 entries, then 10 tables.
On other side we have 1 table where EmployeeID and Type will make composite key against all. The only difference i found is for 10,000 Records if in future 10 fields comes then table will have 1 lakh record.

Comment: Can you enlighten on same if we add more columns then which design is better since you profile shows you are experienced in oracle for quite long. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for udpate.....So for my usecase.... WE need to send data to third party.... data includes userid, email, custno, address. But i need to maintain update date for each of these. I think as per your article i should create seperate table for each attribute like THIRDPARTY_USERID, THIRDPARTY_EMAIL..and store changed value as well as update date in each table separately. Looks straightforward. (The problem with me is that cannot store single update date for all columns, need flag to check what is updated)